# How does one apply different frame rates to videoDataOutput and session's previewLayer in AVFoundation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I am developing an augmented reality application with `AVFoundation`. Basically, I need to start up the camera, provide a instant preview, and get image samples every 1 second. Currently I am using `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` for camera preview, and `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` to get sample frames.

But the problem is, the reasonable frame rate for `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` is way too high for `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`. How can I apply different frame rates to them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no answer yet, so I put my temporary solution here:

Firstly, add a property:

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSTimeInterval lastFrameTimestamp;
```

And the delegate method:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    CMTime timestamp = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer);
    NSTimeInterval currentFrameTimestamp = (double)timestamp.value / timestamp.timescale;
    if (currentFrameTimestamp - self.lastFrameTimestamp > secondsBetweenSampling) {
        self.lastFrameTimestamp = currentFrameTimestamp;
        // deal with the sampleBuffer here
    }
}
```

The idea is pretty simple. As we can see, I just keep the frame rate high so the preview layer is satisfied. But upon receiving an output, I check the timestamp every time to decide whether to deal with that frame or just ignore it.

Still looking for better ideas ;)